# how to create laravel project with latest 8.0 version using cmd?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use latest stable laravel 8.0 version for windows. but I cannot install using cmd. I want to crate new laravel project so I tried with this command which is available in laravel documentation.

cmd command .

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^8.0 blog
```

Comment: Can you share the error when you run this command so you will get the exact answer of your question

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps : https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/ .

- Download the PHP 8 using command and do the needful configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is run a composer script in a PC which does not have PHP installed.

First, download PHP from here;
[PHP Windows download](https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.0)

Then, install composer from here;
[Composer installation instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Both links have instructions on how to proceed with the installations. After you do both these, you can run that composer command in the command line.

I hope you know that composer is a dependency manager and PHP is the interpreter of the language. Happy coding.